# FancyBox reloads current window with blank html

Tags: jquery, asp.net, html, fancybox

I'm trying to get a fancybox to load an ASPX page. It works correctly for other pages, but not this one. The fancybox jQuery code is identical, the html is the same -- everything is the same, except of course the contents of the ASPX file.

So, is there anything that could be in my new page that could cause something like this to happen?

Firebug shows no errors, either, so it isn't like it can't find the page.

---

Here is the element that is **not** working:

```
<a href='../DocumentUpload_SavedOffer.aspx' class="needsFancyBox">Click here to upload offer specific documents.</a>
```

and it's FancyBox code:

```
$("a.needsFancyBox").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': false,
    'padding': 0,
    'type': 'ajax',
    'centerOnScroll': false
});
```

and here is the element that works just fine:

```
<a href="../rets/search.aspx" class="mlsSearch">Search</a>
```

and its FancyBox code:

```
$("a.mlsSearch").fancybox({
    'hideOnContentClick': false,
    'padding': 0,
    'type': 'ajax',
    'centerOnScroll': false
});
```

And note that both anchors are in the same page, and both jQuery fancybox initializers are in the same .js file, which is used site-wide. Both pages being opened are .aspx, both have valid html, etc. There has to be something in one of the .aspx pages that could cause this issue, though.

---

Ok, here is the non-working file. I'm not going to include the rendered html, because a lot of it is going to be very proprietary.

```
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="headerContent" Runat="Server">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../includes/css/datagrid.css" />
    <link href="../includes/css/simpleform.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="bodyContent" Runat="Server">
    <form id="frmMain" runat="server">
        <asp:HiddenField runat="server" ID="hdSavedOfferId" />
        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="lstvwDocuments" DataKeyNames="docId">
            <LayoutTemplate>
                <table class="datagrid" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
                    <tr>
                        <th>Document Title</th>
                        <th>Uploaded By</th>
                        <th style="border: 0px solid #99CC33">Upload Date</th>
                    </tr>
                    <asp:Literal runat="server" ID="itemPlaceholder" />
                </table>
            </LayoutTemplate>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <tr class='<%# Container.DisplayIndex % 2 == 1 ? "item" : "alt" %>'>
                    <td><%# Eval("docTitle") %></td>
                    <td><%# Eval("uploadedBy") %></td>
                    <td style="border: 0px solid #FFF"><%# Eval("uploadDate") %></td>
                </tr>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:ListView>
        <br/>
        <br/>
        <fieldset class="simpleform">
            <legend>Upload Offer Specific Documents Here</legend>
            <dl>
                <dt><asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Document Title" /></dt>
                <dd>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="txtTitle" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate="txtTitle" ErrorMessage="Please enter a title" ForeColor="Red" />
                </dd>
            </dl>
            <dl>
                <dt><asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" Text="Document to Upload" /></dt>
                <dd>
                    <asp:FileUpload ID="file_Image" runat="server" BorderColor="White" />
                    <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator2" runat="server" ControlToValidate="file_Image" ErrorMessage="Please add a document" ForeColor="Red"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                </dd>
            </dl>
            <div style="clear: both;"><br /></div>
            <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="Button1_Click" CssClass="simplebutton" />
            <asp:Label ID="lblResult" runat="server" Text="" />
        </fieldset>
    </form>
</asp:Content>

<asp:Content ID="Content3" ContentPlaceHolderID="footerContent" Runat="Server">
</asp:Content>
```

Comment: @Zlatan it's mostly proprietary. But i'll edit with as much as I can

Comment: 2 things come to my mind.. first: href='../DocumentUpload_SavedOffer.aspx' you should use " double quotes href="../DocumentUpload_SavedOffer.aspx" .. and the other is just to check if the file is on the file system, at that location ".." one directory before.. check this out and let me know..

Comment: @Zlatan why use double quotes? and yes, it has to be, or I would be getting a 404.

Comment: it's a good practice which is accepted widely :)

Comment: `has to be something in one of the .aspx pages that could cause this issue` the only way to know is looking at the (rendered html) code of such page ... got a link?

Comment: @jfk I posted as much as I can. I'm not going to be able to post the actual output html, as first of all, it doesn't get rendered, and second of all, it's proprietary.

Comment: and note that it *is* hitting the page_load for the page, and no exceptions are coming up.